# Force re-authentication with Azure AD

Tags: passport.js, azure-ad-msal

I am using the passport-ad library for my backend to protect my endpoint. How can I make sure that the bearer access token is new (e.g. issued time is within a certain threshold?)

For my frontend using MSAL, what is the best practise to force re-authentication when the user tries to access sensitive info?

Answer (score 4):

Prompt is an optional parameter you can include during the authorization code flow, when the client directs the user to the `/authorize` endpoint. Prompt dictates the type of interaction that is required by the user. In MSAL.NET, you can choose from the following Prompts:

- `SelectAccount` -> force the STS to present the account selection dialog containing a list of accounts for which the user has a session
- `Consent` -> forces the user to be prompted for consent, even if consent was granted previously
- `ForceLogin` -> the user will always be prompted for credentials by the service, even if not necessary (I think this is the one you want, when you say "force re-authentication")
- `NoPrompt` -> no prompt value will be sent and the STS will determine which UI to show the user based on the previous sessions

For example:

```
https://login.microsoftonline.com/{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?
scope=offline_access+openid+profile
&client_id=37efsf6-14a6-44ae-97bc-6eba6916741e
&response_type=code
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%3A12345
&response_mode=query
&resource=https%3A%2F%2Fservice.contoso.com%2F
&state=12345
&prompt=login
```

More info [here](https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-authentication-library-for-dotnet/wiki/Acquiring-tokens-interactively#withprompt).